# 'str' object is not callable - CAUTION: DO NO USE SPECIAL FUNCTIONS AS VARIABLES

Tags: python, string, variables

> EDIT: If you define a predefined type such as: 
>   `str = 5`  then the
>   original functionality of that predefined will change to a new one. Lesson Learnt: **Do not give variables names that are predefined or belong to special functions**. List here: [Here](http://www.diveintopython3.net/special-method-names.html)

Before you mark it as duplicate, please see this python code and results

```
X=5

print("X value is:"+str(X))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "", line 1, in 
>       print("X value is:"+str(X))
>       TypeError: 'str' object is not callable*

As far as I know, str should work here because I am simply printing the value of variable here. Any clues?

Comment: Works fine in mine...`X value is:5`

Comment: This is not the complete code. Copy pasting the two lines `x=5` and `print("x value is:"+str(x))` in a fresh python console results in the desired print

Comment: Have you used `str` as a variable?

Comment: It looks like you've overwritten the Python method `str()` with a string... do you have `str = '<some_string>'` anywhere in your code? Given a fresh environment what you're seeing does not occur, so you're missing something from your question.

Comment: If my version is printing it out as I said, what should I do?

Comment: Not redefining `str` before, believe it...

Comment: If you start up a completely new interpreter and run your code it does what you've said? i.e. you can replicate exactly this behaviour in complete isolation?

Comment: @Ben thank you. Yes I had defined str as a string.

Comment: Can your do a little test see if you have reassign the `str` as your local variable. you can simple test it by print(str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is str function must have been overloaded.

**Input:**

```
X=5
print("X value is:"+str(X))
```

**Output:** 
X value is:5

**Input:**

```
X=5
str = "98897"
print("X value is:"+str(X))
```

**Output:** 
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 print("X value is:"+str(X))

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Got it. must not use predefined types and special functions as variables. Thanks