# Why is Float object not callable?

Tags: python, function, class, oop

Looking at the code I have below as an example. Why is it I get the error "Float object not callable" when using print statement 1 but not print statement 2? what do I need to do to my class if I was wanting to make print statement 1 work?

```
var1 = float(input())

class ExampleClass(object):
    def __init__(self, thing1):
        self.getThing1 = thing1

    def getThing1(self):
        return self.getThing1

a = ExampleClass(var1)

print(str(a.getThing1())) #print statement 1 that doesn't work
print(str(a.getThing1)) #print statement 2 that does work
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['str' object is not callable - different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51319929/str-object-is-not-callable-different)

Answer (score 9):

You are trying to use `getThing1` as a method name *and* an attribute. You declare a method `getThing1`, but then you assign `self.getThing1 = thing1`. So `getThing1` isn't a method anymore; it's the value of `thing1`.

Perhaps you meant this:

```
class ExampleClass(object):
    def __init__(self, thing1):
        self.thing1 = thing1

    def getThing1(self):
        return self.thing1
```

However, `getXXX` methods are *not* the convention in Python. If you need a method wrapping your attribute, you should make it a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
class ExampleClass(object):
    def __init__(self, thing1):
--->    self.getThing1 = thing1
```

shadows this:

```
   def getThing1(self):
       return self.getThing1
```

Python functions are objects don't live in a distinct namepsace, so to make a long story short you cannot have an attribute and a method by the same name.

The solution is simple: don't use `getThing1` as an attribute name - specially since "get" is a verb so it's a poor name for a value.

Also note that Python has a string support for computed attributes so you don't need systematic getters/setters for attributes. You can start with a plain attribute and turn it into a computed one later if the need arises.